# PRISM Region loses Context during navigation

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, prism-4

I created an application using PRISM and it's navigation features. There is main region in this app which `Context` contains current logged user. In this region I dynamically load views using `RegionManager.RequestNavigate`. Views contains other views with separate view models.  It's all fine except that main views exist all the application time and when I go out from view and return back view is the same as it was, i.e. it's not to be created again. What I've done: in the main view models I've implemented `INavigationAware` with `IsNavigationTarget` setted to false. Views are created every time, but there is exception about "could create nested region cause of it's already registered". Then in main view model I implemeted `IRegionMemberLifetime` with setted `KeepAlive` to false. It's all fine but when navigate from view and navigate to it again main regions's `Context` loses it's content.

How can I Fix it?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I prepared working sample [PrismNavigationSample.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=09f9aac932650216&resid=9F9AAC932650216!140) for fully understanding my question.

Try this in both projects: Go to a first view, change slider value, return back and go to the first view again. Also see on Context value on the window above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer on the [Codeplex](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/276663#post687407). See [RegionContext lost when removing a view from a region](http://blogs.southworks.net/aadami/2011/09/22/prism-v4-regioncontext-lost-when-removing-a-view-from-a-region/) for more details.

Comment: Your link does not work what was it?

Comment: @Dev Sorry I don't remember. Please try to find that page in cache